# C# 8.0 notnull Generic Type Contraint

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I'm trying to use the just-released .NET Standard 2.1 C# 8.0 features in VS2019 Preview 16.4.0 but keep receiving the message "Cannot resolve symbol 'notnull'".

My example code:

```
class Example<T> where T : notnull {}
```

I have the `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` and `<LangVersion>8</LangVersion>` property set in my project file and all of that new functionality is working great, it just seems to be this.

How can I use the `notnull` type contraint?

Comment: what is the language level set for this project?

Comment: @Adassko I've set the LangVersion property to 8 in the project file. I'll update my question to include that

Comment: I can't find information that this is released already. Have you tried setting LangVersion to "preview"?

Comment: I've tried using preview and I've tried setting my project target to netcoreapp3.0 but neither changes anything.
I've seen it referenced in some Microsoft documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/

Comment: try to remove "obj" and "bin" folders, restart VS or even your pc. might be just a random thing. Are you able to compile it and run regardless of that message? It happened to me in the past that IDE was showing some non existing errors for new functionalities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because C# 8.0 is not enabled.

In some preview versions of .NET Core 3.0 SDK, C# 8.0 was a `preview` version rather than `latest` or `latestMajor` version which is taken as the default language version.

But at least in .NET Core 3.0 GA (formal release version), C# 8.0 is enabled by default if your project targets `netcoreapp3.0`. But as for `netstandard2.1` target, the default language version is still 7.3.

If you really need to share this library with the latest Xamarin apps that supports .NET Standard 2.1, specify `<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>` explicitly in the `.csproj` file within `PropertyGroup`, or you just set the `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp3.0` and C# 8.0 should be enabled by default.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I did have the ```<LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>``` property specified in my project file but VS wasn't recognising it. I reloading the project and the syntax highlighting started working again.
Your answer is definitely the right one though, thank you!

Comment: I've also found that ReSharper will sometimes mark these newer language features like this even though Visual Studio itself still builds fine. I imagine newer version of ReSharper will improve their support and fix these issues over time.